# How to render / display multiframe dicom images in vtk?

Tags: vtk, gdcm

I am using gdcm ImageReader to read multiframe dicom file. It reads multiframe correctly but I am unable to display the multiframe dicom file.

I am using vtkImageViewer to display single frame image,

```
  vtkImageViewer viewer = new vtkImageViewer();  
  vtkDICOMImageReader reader = new vtkDICOMImageReader();   
  reader.SetInputfile(..\\inputFile);  
  viewer.SetInput(reader.GetOutput());
```

It displays single frame images correctly but does not display multiframe images.
Anybody knows how to display multiframe dicom files???

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use `vtkImageViewer2` instead of `vtkImageViewer` in this context. The former has a method, `SetSlice`, where, according to the [documentation](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkImageViewer2.html#details):

'*Each call to SetSlice() changes the image data (slice) displayed AND changes the depth of the displayed slice in the 3D scene*'

Example**:

`vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageViewer2> imageViewer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageViewer2>::New();
imageViewer->SetSlice(5); //Specify the index/slice in image data`

** Assumes you have set the input connection/data, example in c++ language.